# Animating and rotating images in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, opengl-es, core-graphics, rotation

I have a set of 36 car images which I need to be interactive. i.e., using the touchesMoved, touchesEnded methods. Tapping any part of the car should display a popover depending on which part is below the tap.

For example,

The user swipes left and the car rotates left. He then selects the front door or some other part and depending on the part selected, I can present a popover with options.

I am experienced in iOS app development but not well versed in animations and interactions such as these.

I am confused whether to use CoreGraphics or openGL.Can someone point me in the right direction? Some sample code or link to any material is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to draw sprites (flat images), then [take a third option](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TakeAThirdOption): [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/). Represent each car in a UIView, and use the view's CALayer to actually display the car and make it animatable.

If you want to draw the car as a three-dimensional object, then there are no two ways around it: You must use OpenGL ES.

At least until GL Kit arrives. You'll still be using OpenGL ES, but that should make it easier. The catch is, [you'll have to require iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/).

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL requires you to do everything yourself. It gives you powerfull drawing tools, but you must master them for them to be usefull. But in the end OpenGL boils down being pencils, brushes and masks. There's no kind of support like an animation system, graphics objects and so on.

Those must be implemented by a higher layer. Either written by yourself, or by third party. CoreGraphics essentially is such a layer. You task sound a lot like blending between a number of images based on user swipe and reacting to taps.

This can be done using OpenGL (heck I probably would be quicker coding that in OpenGL, than if I first had to learn the use of CoreGraphics), but if you're an OpenGL novice then CoreGraphics may be the better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but I will mark @Peter answer as correct as it is more specific to my platform.